# how to get first character from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

- I need to create brand for an eCommerce site.
- I need a solution that gives me first character from an array.
- I tried some code but it was not so useful.
- I need brand like I mentioned bellow.

like

```
A             
Alpha
Aloo
Amakeaviral

B
Boki
Bone
```

my data coming from database, in a array.
I need first character from array.

**I tried:**

```
$my_array = array("Alpha", "Aloo", "Amakeaviral", "Boki", "Bone");

for($i = 0; $i <= count($my_array); $i++){
    $first_char = $my_array[$i]{0}; 
    echo $first_char;
}
```

but this not working well.
How can I do this?

Comment: you should use `$my_array[$i][0]`. Also your loop is wrong it should be `$i < count($my_array)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hope this will work for you -

```
$my_array = array("Alpha","Aloo","Amakeaviral","Boki","Bone");
$newArray = array();
foreach($my_array as $value) {
   $first_char = $value[0];
   if (!empty($newArray)) {
       $flag = false;
       foreach ($newArray as $key => $val) {
           if ($first_char == $key){
                $newArray[$key][] = $value;
                $flag = true;
           }
       }
       if (!$flag) {
           $newArray[$first_char][] = $first_char;
           $newArray[$first_char][] = $value;
       }
   } else {
        $newArray[$first_char][] = $first_char;
        $newArray[$first_char][] = $value;
   }
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

Same as above but shortened code:

```
$my_array = array("Alpha","Aloo","Amakeaviral","Boki","Bone");
$newArray = array();
foreach($my_array as $value) {
    if (empty($newArray[$value[0]])){
        $newArray[$value[0]][]=$value[0];
    }
    $newArray[$value[0]][] = $value;
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: omg so much code? Try `foreach($my_array as $value) {
    if (empty($newArray[$value[0]])){
        $newArray[$value[0]][]=$value[0];
    }
    $newArray[$value[0]][] = $value;
}
` for same efect!

Comment: @bansi hope you can do what is wanted in much less code and add the answer. i couldnt.

Comment: I can add the shortened version to this answer

Comment: the above will be an array with indexes with the first character.for the next array how can you differentiate the first character if needed with the values?

Comment: `$value[0]` is first character and it is used for the array key.So you will be storing the correct value to the correct key always!

Comment: got it now... missed that thing. :)

Answer (score 11):

Try with `substr()` as simply short

```
$my_array = array("Alpha", "Aloo", "Amakeaviral", "Boki", "Bone");
foreach($my_array as $v){
    echo substr($v, 0, 1);
}
```

or your code:- remove `=` from loop `<=`(else you will get notices) and use `[]` rather `{}`

```
$my_array = array("Alpha", "Aloo", "Amakeaviral", "Boki", "Bone");
for($i=0; $i < count($my_array); $i++){
    $first_char = $my_array[$i][0]; 
    echo $first_char;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Finding first character

```
substr("Hello", 0, 1); //output "H"
```

Try:

```
$first_char = substr($my_array[$i], 0, 1);
```

Full code:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($my_array); $i++){
    echo $first_char = substr($my_array[$i], 0, 1); 
}
```

Note: `$i <= count($my_array)` should be `$i < count($my_array)`

## [Live DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4amg-nrfi)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, every string is an array and can be accessed like it:

```
$str = 'This is a string';
echo $str[0]; // Output: T
echo $str[1]; // Output: h
echo $str[2]; // Output: i
```

Just change this:

```
$first_char = $my_array[$i]{0};
```

into this:

```
$first_char = $my_array[$i][0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$my_array = array("Alpha", "Aloo", "Amakeaviral", "Boki", "Bone");
foreach($my_array as $v){
    echo $v[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit old I'm sorry but this is how I did it with an array of objects. I wanted to display the title of each object in an alphabetised page. I used the following:

```
$items = array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [title] => Alpha
        [name] => Joe Blogs
        [address] => 123 Harry Street
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [title] => Bravo
        [name] => Jane Doe
        [address] => 456 Upton Street
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [title] => Charlie
        [name] => Jane Doe
        [address] => 456 Upton Street
    )

)
```

Then declared this function in a helper class

```
public static function alphaSortItems ($items) {
        $sortedItems = array();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $sortedItems[$item->title[0]][] = $item;
        }
        return $sortedItems;
    }
```

Then to display them I used

```
 <?php $sortedItems = Helper::alphaSortItems($this->items); ?>
        <?php foreach ($sortedItems as $key => $value) : ?>
            <h2><?php echo $key; ?></h2>
            <?php foreach ($value as $item) : ?>
                <h3><?php echo $item->title; ?></h3>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

That's how I did it anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
$my_array = array("Alpha", "Aloo", "Amakeaviral", "Boki", "Bone");

for($i = 0; $i < count($my_array); $i++){
    $first_char = $my_array[$i][0]; 
    echo $first_char;
}
```

Comment: <= you will get undefined index notice?

Comment: Hey @Riteshdjoshi, I just did some formatting changes, just to make it look a bit more beautiful, nothing else!